# How to prevent Mercurial commits/pushes of certain files?

Tags: mercurial

At a point in our development process we send all *.resx files to a translator. The translator usually takes a week to send back the files. During this time no one is allowed to add, remove or update any resx file.

How can I configure mercurial to enforce that policy?

Our setup: Each dev works with a local clone of our central repository.

Nice to have:

1. I'll turn the "policy" on and off every few weeks. So ideally, I'd like something that is easy to configure at one place and that affect all devs.
2. I'd rather enforce that policy at the local repository level then at the central repository level because if we prevent the "push" on the central repository, it will be harder for the dev to undo the already locally committed changeset.

Thanks

---

**UPDATE:**

More info on the translation process:

Merging is not an issue here. The translator does not change the files that we sent to him. We send him a bunch of language neutral .resx (form1.resx) and returns a bunch of language specific resx (form1.FR.resx).

Why prevent adding new resx? Adding a resx occurs when we add a new UI to our application. If we do that after the translation package has been sent, the translator won't know about the new UI and we'll end up with a new UI with no translation.

Why prevent updating resx? If the dev changes a label value from "open" to "close", he has made a very important semantic change. If he does that after the translation package has been sent, we won't get the right translation back.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot stop by people from committing changes to `.resx` files unless you have control over their desktop machines (using a `pretxncommit` hook), and even then it's easily bypassed.  It's much more normal to put the check on the central server at time of `push` using a `pretxnchangegroup` hook, but you're right that they'll have to fix up any changesets and re-push, which is advanced usage.  In either case you'd used the [AclExtension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/AclExtension) to enforce the actual restriction.

Here are two alternate ways to go about this that might work out better for you:

1. Clone your repository at the start of the translation process, warn developers to leave .resx alone for awhile, apply the work of the translators when they're done, and then merge those changes back into the main development repository with a [merge command that always gives the incoming changes priority](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Keep_.22My.22_or_.22Their.22_files_when_doing_a_merge): X .  Then use a simple `hg log` command to find all the changes in `.resx` that just got overwritten and tell the developers to re-add them.  Chide them at this time.

alternately

1. Make the .resx files a [Subrepository](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository) of the larger outer repository.  Then turn off write access to that resx repository during the forbidden period.  Developers will be able to commit in the outer repository but not the inner one, but clones will still get both exactly as they always did.

For what it's worth, everyone else handles this problem with simple merging, .resx is (XML) text, and it merges just fine.

When working with a DVCS it's not always easy to exactly mirror your svn experience, but there's usually a better option anyway.

Comment: I'll check the AclExtension. The resx files are scattered across multiple directories in the project folder, a sub repository would not work well in that context. I'm not doing all that to ease the merging process. I have updated my question with more info on why we do that.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense.  You'll be able to do what you want at the push level using AclExtension.  I still think the notion that this is a very common situation and everyone else manages to address it without resorting to a blocking hook should give you pause.  For example, here's how the Mercurial project itself, which relies on a great many volunteer translators whose work happens during and after the coding, handles it: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TranslatingMercurial

Answer (score 0):

You could add *.resx to the hgignore file

Comment: I don't like this idea because the dev won't notice that his changes to the resx are ignored. If a dev "has to" change a resx for a good reason during the translation process, we a have to know that because that work will have to be done when the translator sends the files back.

Comment: It won't work either.  The `.hgignore` file is only consulted when considering **untracked** files.  Once a file has already been added/tracked (as these .resx files are) then `.hgignore` has no effect at all.