# How to stop mercurial from syncing an EXISTING project file

Tags: mercurial

So the problem is that all developers need different settings for their local testing, but the settings file is part of the project (unlike the nbproject folder for example that we all `ignore`). I know about `.htignore`, but the filter only applies to files that are not part of the project.

If I `forget` the file, then this removes it from the "global" repository, where we have a "holder" version of the settings file.

Right now we just don't commit that file, but every now and then somebody forgets and pushes his own settings, which then are synced back to other developers and it's a constant pain. We just want to "automatically" not push that file. Is there a solution to this? Are we doing something wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent Mercurial commits/pushes of certain files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274419/how-to-prevent-mercurial-commits-pushes-of-certain-files)

Answer (score 1):

You could add a [precommit hook](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HookExamples) that gives an error every time you try to commit this particular file.

To handle the case of developers that forget to setup such a hook, you can also add a serverside hook that will reject their push.

Comment: Well, that must have been the most disheartening intro message I ever read. Sounds like quite the trouble but if nothing better pops up I might give it a go. Thanks.